# Save views in multiple screen terminals

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen

As I do in default single view screen terminal of ubuntu;

```
 gnome-terminal \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --working-directory="some dir" --title="some title" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --working-directory="another dir" --title="title" \
```

I save above command in an executable file and open multiple terminals in single execution. But it opens default terminal only.

Can I save screen with multiple views such that I can open all in a single click(if it can be bookmarked) or by running single command?

**Multiview screen application for ubuntu**: terminal multiplexer (tmux), terminator, screen ...

Comment: [You can do this with tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggested link of @jasonwryan, I created following script to solve my problem;

```
cd dir1
tmux new-window -a -n WinSplit
tmux new-session -d -s WinSplit
tmux selectp -t WinSplit
tmux split-window -v
cd dir2
tmux select-pane -U
tmux split-window -h
cd dir3
tmux split-window -v
#tmux select-layout even-vertical
tmux attach -t WinSplit

tmux bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
tmux bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
tmux bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
tmux bind -n M-Down select-pane -D
```